# Symfony 1.0 i18n and layout rendering

Tags: php, layout, internationalization, symfony1

I have a problem with symfony 1.0. Everything works fine until I change culture. Than layout file is not loaded at all - only few templates, but no head section, no footer, etc.

I'm quite new to symfony, but I checked settings (`i18n is on`), and translation system (`line __()` ) is working fine, but no main layout is shown.

Can you please point where to look for the problem?

Comment: Do you have error_reporting turned on in your settings.yml file?

Comment: yes, error reporting is set to 4095 (E_ALL)